# options in compression with 7z

Tags: windows, 7-zip, c#

I want to create an archive, through a program I am writing in C#, and later decompress it.

The archive will contain folders from completely different locations, grouped on 3 major subdivisions.

Basically, group A can have folders \x\y\z, \x\y\m, \x\p\q, group B can have folders \x\p\r, \x\y\t... So the original location can give only slight indication of the division, I can't use the path for grouping.

I was hoping that I can use 7z options to place folders in different folders inside the zip, but I couldn't find any such options, so I thought I will create 3 zips inside one big zip.

The problem I see is, the amount of data is big (hundreds, thousands of GB) and as far as I know, zip over zip is not a great idea. (data types: mostly image type, could be tif or other uncompressed formats, but may also be jpg)

It would be actually great if I could do zip over rar... But 7z doesn't use rar on compression, only on decompression.

I don't want to have to install multiple programs - I will only install 7z.

7z has, for packing, the following options (from their site): 7z, XZ, BZIP2, GZIP, TAR, ZIP and WIM. I would use one of them for the inner archives and then the 7z option for the outer archive.

What is the best option ? (to get a better archive that doesn't create a bigger zip than by just doing it all in one pass)

Edit: Windows !

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, if in fact there's a question.

Comment: edited, I hope I made it clear

Comment: I'd do tar.gz, honestly. Create a tarball of each of the groups you need, and then gzip the whole lot. However, this is going to take a very long time due to the size of the archives.

Comment: I'd do tar.xz instead - xzip uses essentially the same LZMA-based algorithm as 7z, which compresses a large corpus a lot better, especially if there's a lot of repeated data across different files.  If you're going to use 7zip, use its own .7z format, for the same reason.

Comment: A great point. +1 for xzip.

Comment: So can I do tar.7z ?

Comment: Most of you seem to have lost sight of what the actual problem/question was in the OP. The "problem" as he stated it was that he wanted to divide separate topics up by subfolder within the archive, but since he didn't see a way to do that using the 7z command, he thought he'd resort to nested zip files. The nested zip files is NOT a requirement of his question, only an artifact of his confusion about archive folder structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on Linux, you can create symbolic links to the folder paths on your hard drive and add those folders to the archive. Heck, you can do this on Windows with symbolic links, too.

So, example:

You have folders `/a`, `/b`, `/c` and `/d` (on Windows this would be `C:\a`, etc.)

Your desired folder structure inside the archive is:

```
/SUBDIVISION-1/a
/SUBDIVISION-1/b
/SUBDIVISION-2/c
/SUBDIVISION-3/d
```

or some arbitrary split of the folders between subdivisions.

So when you go to compress, you'd just

```
mkdir /SUBDIVISION-1
mkdir /SUBDIVISION-2
mkdir /SUBDIVISION-3
```

Then

```
ln -s /a /SUBDIVISION-1/a
ln -s /b /SUBDIVISION-1/b
ln -s /c /SUBDIVISION-2/c
ln -s /d /SUBDIVISION-3/d
```

and you can have an arbitrary number of directories within each subdivision, from 0 to 1 to `N`.

On Windows you can't use the `ln` command; you'll have to use the [mklink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) command instead.

You'll need a program that's smart enough to follow symbolic links (on Linux), but on Windows, it should be automatic... the archive shouldn't just plop a symlink in there; it should have the data found after dereferencing the symlink. At least that's how it should be if you use the Win32 subsystem (which I infer 7z does).

Windows version upon implicit request from OP (from `cmd.exe` shell):

```
mkdir C:\SUBDIVISION-1
mkdir C:\SUBDIVISION-2
mkdir C:\SUBDIVISION-3
```

Then

```
mklink /d C:\SUBDIVISION-1\a C:\a
mklink /d C:\SUBDIVISION-1\b C:\b
mklink /d C:\SUBDIVISION-2\c C:\c
mklink /d C:\SUBDIVISION-3\d C:\d
```

Comment: Windows :-( Edit my question too. Thanks, I'll try this, not sure how from my program, but it is what I want !

Comment: It should work fine on Windows, you'll just have to use different paths and a different symlink command.

Comment: After testing a number of combinations, I found out that I must be an administrator in order to be able to create symbolic links... (???)

Comment: Yep, correct. Or install Cygwin and use its symbolic link emulation and the `7za` compressor from there....

Comment: I am not as flexible - I don't think - I have cygwin, but I am doing this from a C# program (Calling a "CreateSymbolicLink" function) so using cygwin is probably not going to help.

Comment: Gah. Why didn't you mention you are writing a program? BTW, this belongs on StackOverflow and not SuperUser since it's related to programming. Anyway, you shouldn't be calling any command line utilities to do this. From a programming language you can very easily just create directories declaratively within the archive, if you're using the LZMA SDK C# bindings -- see http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

Comment: I know... If I wasn't able to just call command line, I was going to add the sdk - I added it tentatively, but that presents other kind of complications for what I am doing (and I thought this would be easier, obviously it isn't).  I'll see if I like it using the sdk. Thank you.

Comment: Never call a command from a program when you can do it from code... adding an external dependency like that makes your code fragile and you depend on the existence of files, you run into potential errors with file paths, you run into issues with the downstream program parsing command line options, etc. Stick to code, APIs that you can control and concretely see and debug.